# Problems using PackageLoader to load the wrench class

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to load the Wrench library using [PackageLoader](https://github.com/Wilkins/composer-file-loader) and I can't get it to work. My code is below.

```
include __DIR__.'/PackageLoader.php';
$loader = new PackageLoader\PackageLoader();
$loader->load(__DIR__."/vendor/wrench/wrench");

$app = new class implements \Wrench\Application\DataHandlerInterface
{
    public function onData(string $data, \Wrench\Connection $connection): void
    {
        $connection->send($data);
    }
};
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Interface 'Wrench\Application\DataHandlerInterface' not found in C:\Users\desbest\Documents\UniServerZ\www\sugarchat\includes\actions.php on line 13

It finds the `composer.json` file though when I load the library.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the directories right? Why don't you use Composer as it should be used?

Comment: The directories are correct. I don't want to use Composer as I don't like it and I'm only making a simple script.

Comment: Could you add your `DataHandlerInterface` as well as the path to your file?

Comment: And I assume you set your root directory in some sort of config (`define('ROOT', 'path/to/root/');`)?

Comment: How do I add the `DataHandlerInterface`? I don't see any of that on Composer File Loader.

Comment: There is no file  \Wrench\Application\DataHandlerInterface

Comment: Which version of `Wrench` you're using?

Comment: This is a bad question.  You are asking how to nail something with duct tape.

Wrench\Application\DataHandlerInterface

Is a namespace.  You need to register this namespace to use it.  Composer does this for you.  Composer is we refer to as a "package manager" because when you use a "package" it "manages" it (as in registering the namespaces for you).  If you want to try getting something to work without the right tools, you are causing yourself a bigger headache in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Having created the structure shown in the screenshot your code is executed without errors

[image]

your script is in the file wrench.php in the screenshot and I just called it on cli

```
php wrench.php
```

There isn't any useful code yet but it seems everything is loading fine at least.

As you can see I cloned wrench inside the structure of `composer-file-loader` and created the structure like used in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a namespace that is not registered.  Composer does this for you, and I would therefore, recommend using composer.

If you are set on not using composer you need to use the function [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

```
spl_autoload_register([
     'Wrench\\Application\\DataHandlerInterface' => 'PATH/TO/FILE.php'
]);
```